# Как реализовать таймер с условием на ардуино?

Tags: arduino

Дайте дельный совет:

Хочу реализовать следующие.

Таймер минутный который будет заставлять каждую минуту поворачивать шаговый двигатель три раза в вправо.

Например: я устанавливаю таймер на 5 минут, запускаю, каждую минуту двигатель делает 3 оборота. После 5 минут процесс завершается и ардуино подает сигнал.

Может есть готовые решения? Или примерные варианты?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот такие девайсы есть в распоряжении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов.
Первый  - прицепить модуль реального времени и написать условие, по которому каждое определённое время запускать нужный код.
Второй - таймер на millis() - счетчике миллисекунд от запуска ардуины. Пример [здесь](https://alexgyver.ru/gyvertimer/)

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет!  Я просто первый раз работаю с ардуино, и немного не понятен алгоритм действий.

Comment: Тогда стоит начать с вводных уроков по ардуино, мигание светодиода там например =)